# Unable to find remote event receiver template in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio, event-receivers, remote-event-receiver, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a remote event receiver solution for SharePoint Online using VS 2019 community edition. I created an empty SP Add-in project, but when I try to add a new item, the event receiver template is not present. In fact, Office/SharePoint node itself is missing (attached screenshot). The same happens for VS 2022 community edition as well. Office/SharePoint dev tools is already installed.

Could you please help me figure out what I'm missing here?

[image: Add new item page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You selected **Add > New item** on the Web project. Try instead to select **Add > New item** on the AddIn project.

[image]